# Conditionally change Akka.Persistence Recovery object

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-persistence

I am trying to conditionally change an actor's Recovery object.  When an actor spins up and there are no snapshots or events that have been persisted, I restart the actor.  Upon restarting I want to change the `Recovery` object.  This is how I currently have my actor set up:

```
protected Recovery _recovery = Recovery.Default;
public override Recovery Recovery => _recovery;
```

And in the `PostRestart()` method, I have:

```
protected override void PostRestart(Exception reason)
{
    // EmptyJournalException is a custom exception
    if (reason is EmptyJournalException)
    {
        // Other code here...
        _recovery = new Recovery(SnapshotSelectionCriteria.None);
    }
}
```

However, when going through the recovery process again, it is still applying snapshots.  If I change the value of `_recovery` to ignore snapshots *in the constructor*, it works as expected.  However, when setting it in `PostRestart()`, it gets ignored.

What is the best way to conditionally set the `Recovery` property?  I am wanting to only set it when restarting the actor because of an `EmptyJournalException`.

Comment: Why are you using exceptions to control flow of a recovery process? It's one of the first antipatterns from 101 courses about object oriented programming.

Comment: @Horusiath, when an actor spins up and there is nothing persisted for that actor, I want to recover from a different actor (an aggregate).  This was working great, but then I realized it was also trying to apply snapshots from the aggregate actor.  I was wanting to prevent that.  How would you propose I handle that instead?

Comment: After persistent actor recovery process finishes, an [OnReplaySuccess](http://getakka.net/api/Akka.Persistence.Eventsourced.html#Akka_Persistence_Eventsourced_OnReplaySuccess) method is called - you can combine that easily with [LastSequenceNr](http://getakka.net/api/Akka.Persistence.Eventsourced.html#Akka_Persistence_Eventsourced_LastSequenceNr) to determine if actor managed to store any events. LastSequenceNr is a monotonic counter which is incremented with every persisted event and restored as part of recovery process. If it's 0, it means that no event has been persisted by that actor.